# Angular 13 Multiple Entry Points Code Coverage

Tags: angular, karma-coverage

I have a workspace I scaffolded with @angular/cli@13.0.1 and it has multiple 'projects' in it.  If I run `ng test <main project name>` it will combine all of the tests from each entry point into a single bundle and run them all at once.  This is great, it only takes ~30s to do this.  I can't figure out how to collect coverage from this type of test run though.

The closest I can get is define a test architect for each entry point in `angular.json`, but building a browser bundle for each entry point ends up taking a large amount of time given this library has ~41 entry points.  Also with that approach, it's still left as an exercise for the reader to aggregate all those coverage reports into a single report as an additional step.

Does anyone have any examples of collecting and aggregating code coverage from a library with multiple entry points?

Answer (score 0):

After some digging, I discovered I only had to set `projects.<main-project>.sourceRoot` to `projects/<main-project>` instead of `projects/<main-project>/src` in `angular.json`.  This causes the entire repo to be bundled once, all tests run, and coverage collected in a very short amount of time as compared to doing each entry point in isolation and then trying to aggregate the coverage.